# Print bibliography from a general bib file reading it from chapter folders

Tags: bibliographies

Maybe is a little bit missleading, but my problem is that i have a file divided with chapters, with a folder for each chapter. I want to make a unique bib file out of every forder and reference it within a chapter text. The chapter text detects the bib file outside the folder of the chapter (since it refers to the bibliiography like [1]) but when I type in the maestro file, where there are the inputs of the chapters, \printbibliography it told me that it iis empty. What is going on? and, how can I print my bibliography?

```
   \input{cap1/principal}
\input{cap2/principal}
\input{cap3/principal}
\input{cap4/principal}
\input{cap5/principal}
\input{cap6/principal}

\printbibliography
```

this is iin the mmain file

then i want to cite in cap4:

```
\chapter{Efecto de las variables}
\label{chap:cuarto}
%\chapterauthor{Fulano deTal y Mengano Cualquiera} % Sin autor en el índice
% \chapterauthor{} % Autor en el índice

\input{cap4/intro}

\section{Efecto del número de Mach}
\input{cap4/mach}

\section{Efecto del numero de palas}
\input{cap4/palas}

\section{Efecto del cambio de cuerda en la pala}
\input{cap4/cuerda}
```

This is in the chapter 4 main file

this is in palas.tex where the reference is

```
Finalmente se puede concluir que \cite{cap1_libro1}:\\
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a minimal example of what you tried?

Comment: Unless you do something about that with additional packages (which you haven't mentioned) when you compile your main document *all* relative file paths (for example paths file `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}`) will be resolved relative to the current working directory, which should almost always be the directory where your main `.tex` file lives. So if you want a separate file for each chapter, you probably want something like `\addbibresource{./cap1/refs.bib}`, `\addbibresource{./cap2/refs.bib}`, ..., `\addbibresource{./cap6/refs.bib}` in your main `.tex` file.

Comment: Note that unless you do something about it, all `.bib` entries must be unique *across* all `.bib` files. So a reference called, say `sigfridsson`, can only be included in one of the six `.bib` files (in the usual setup it can be *cited* in all chapters, but it can only be included in the `.bib` file of one chapter). It is possible to restrict the scope of `.bib` files to certain parts of a document, but that usually means that it is not possible to get a global `\printbibliography` at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't quite understand what exactly your setup is with regards to `.bib` files, what you get at the moment and what you would like to see instead. A fully compilable example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) instead of code snippets may help, but I appreciate that the `\input`-based setup makes creation of such an MWE hard. In any case it would help if you could share your project folder structure with us (what files are where and what is supposed to happen with them)?